# Same seed in two different editors give me different results (Pycharm and Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, random-seed

I have the following code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)  # To view all the variables in the console

# read data
records = []
with open('./data/data_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        record = json.loads(line)
        records.append(record)

# construct list of ids
ids = set()
for record in records:
    for w in record['A']:
        ids.add(w['NAME'])

random.seed(1234); sampled_ids = random.sample(ids,50)
```

When I run this code one time in Pycharm IDE and then immediately after in a Jupyter Notebook - I get different ids sampled in each one. What's going on?

P.S
I used the semicolon on the last line because I found out that if I try to set the seed on one line and then sample on the next line - **even in the same IDE** I get different results each run. This is truly mysterious to me. I use Python 3.7

Comment: @Carcigenicate its the same version, in the same virtual env (which I created for this project)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I checked again - they are both set to use 3.7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of such a behaviour is lying in `set`. `Set` is constructed from objects based on their `hash` values (the elements of a set must be hashable, i.e. must have [`__hash__` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)), and `hash` values differ when starting another console. (Not always, but that's another theme).
For example, there are results from two consols in the same IDE:

**1/A**:

```
arr1 = set('skevboa;gj[pvemoeprnjpdbr ]p')
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(arr1, 3)
Out[47]: ['p', 'k', ']']
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(arr1, 3)
Out[48]: ['p', 'k', ']']
hash('s')
Out[49]: 1861403979552045688
```

**2/A**:

```
arr1 = set('skevboa;gj[pvemoeprnjpdbr ]p')
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(arr1, 3)
Out[29]: [';', 'a', 'b']
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(arr1, 3)
Out[30]: [';', 'a', 'b']
hash('s')
Out[31]: -2409441490032867064
```

Knowing the source of problem you can choose a method to solve the issue. For example, using `sorted`:

**1/A**:

```
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(sorted(arr1), 3)
Out[50]: ['p', ']', ' ']
```

**2/A**:

```
random.seed(1234)
random.sample(sorted(arr1), 3)
Out[32]: ['p', ']', ' ']
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem! Can you explain why `sorted()` fixes it? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: @Corel `random.sample` returns `k` (`3` in your case) elements based on randomly generated indices. Initializing `random.seed` you preserve index generation. Since `sorted` returns a sorted list, the same values are returned always. `set` [implicitly turned into a tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e28aff54d95236ea1b64b648d89a1516e446e621/Lib/random.py#L367) inside `sample` and since `set` is unordered returned values are values at the same indices but according to current order in `tuple`.